# Multi-field type ahead search box in html and javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, search-box

I am trying to create a search box for searching structured data, where all the fields are known. I want to create a type ahead search box which has two types of typeaheads: 1. Type ahead for fields 2. Type ahead for values of a specific field. Image below shows what I am trying to achieve.

[image]

I already have the backends ready to serve typeaheads and searches. I am not able to figure out how to create a custom text field that can submit multiple form values and query multiple typeahead backends

This is a lot like gmail or kibana search boxes. Will appreciate examples or if someone can point me in the correct direction.

PS: A complete javascript newbie here. I can only understand pure js or jquery.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using a jquery library would be easy option to this. Looking at your question, i think [select2](https://select2.org/getting-started/basic-usage) or [bootstrap multiselect](http://davidstutz.de/bootstrap-multiselect/) could probably help you.

Comment: I did look at both and tried to use them to solve my problem. To be honest, neither of them have what I am looking for. My problem is more of a nested typeahead, if you will.

Comment: oh ok!.. will surely let you know if i found something!